# How to prove that this next limit doesn't exist with the path method

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,\,y)\to(1,\,1)}\frac{xy-x-y+1}{x^2+y^2-2x-2y+2}$$

I've been trying to solve it, but I'm often really confused about these sorts of limits, I would really appreciate some help as to how to demonstrate that this one doesn't exist.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint: change variables to $X=x-1,\,Y=y-1$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the given limit exists if and only if for *any* sequence of points $\{(x_n, y_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $(x_n, y_n) \to (1, 1)$, $f(x_n, y_n) \to a$, where $a$ is some fixed element of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is defined by

$$f(x, y) = \frac{xy - x - y + 1}{x^2 + y^2 -2x -2y + 2}.$$

Thus, to show that the given limit does not exist, it suffices to find two sequences of points $\{(x_n, y_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $\{(x'_n, y'_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where both $(x_n, y_n) \to (1, 1)$, $(x'_n, y'_n) \to (1, 1)$, but where

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n, y_n) \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x'_n, y'_n).$$

The naive method for picking sequences $\{(x_n, y_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $\{(x'_n, y'_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is to pick ones that simplify the expression for $f(x, y)$ by eliminating one of the variables $x, y$. This makes it easier to evaluate the limit. For example, we can pick a sequence of points $(x_n, y_n)$ that lie on the line $y = x$ and converge to $(1, 1)$, and a sequence of points $(x'_n, y'_n)$ that lie on the line $y = 1$ and converge to $(1, 1)$. Then it is easy to check that

$$\lim_{(x_n, y_n) \to (1, 1)} \frac{x_ny_n - x_n - y_n + 1}{x_n^2 + y_n^2 -2x_n -2y_n + 2} = \lim_{x_n \to 1} \frac{x_n^2 - 2x_n + 1}{2x_n^2 -4x_n + 2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

while

$$\lim_{(x'_n, y'_n) \to (1, 1)} \frac{x_ny_n - x_n - y_n + 1}{x_n^2 + y_n^2 -2x_n -2y_n + 2} = \lim_{x_n \to 1} \frac{x_n - x_n - 1 + 1}{x_n^2 + 1 -2x_n -2 + 2} = 0.$$

Since these limits do not agree, the limit

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (1, 1)} \frac{xy - x - y + 1}{x^2 + y^2 -2x -2y + 2}$$

does not exist.